# Set HttpResponseMessage headers from within the Get method of my controller

Tags: rest, odata, transfer-encoding, asp.net-apicontroller

I have a REST service using Web API 2.0 and MVC 5. My controller derives from EntitySetController. I have a Get method that returns the resource as an IQueryable. My question is how do I access the HttpResponseMessage object from within the Get function so that I can set some header values like the TransferEncodingChunked = true.

Answer (score 0):

You could try returning HttpResponseMessage instead and specify return code like that:

```
Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, entitiesGoHere);
```

Comment: That's correct. But if you want to override the Get() from the EntitySetController the return type is an IQueryable. The PUT, POST, DELETE all return HttpResponseMessage and so it is easy to set the header values on the return object that you create with in the method.